# How to mock entity framework DbRawSqlQuery object using moq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

```
var parentid = uow.SqlQuery<int?>("select query", new SqlParameter("Id", Id));
```

uow is object of unit of work.

`SqlQuery` method is as below:

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<T> SqlQuery<T>(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters);
}
```

How to mock below code in c#?

```
var parentid = uow.SqlQuery<int?>("select query", new SqlParameter("Id", Id));
```

Comment: hmm. how does the code you want to test look like? What do you want to test? I think that is the question. The answer to your question is that you need to add an interface or abstract class. But to put that in context, we need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the classes in the example are mockable with moq as they are concrete classes and the methods in question are not virtual. To make it more test friendly, abstract those classes behind abstractions you control. Try not to mock interfaces and classes that you do not control.

The above example is still tightly coupled to implementation concerns `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`. separate it from concretions and have it rely on abstractions `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public interface IExecuteSql {
    int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters);
    IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters);
}

public interface IUnitOfWork : IExecuteSql, //...other interfaces
{
    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

The implementations will wrap the concretions

```
public class EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {

    //...other code removed for brevity

    public int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters) {
        return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters) {
        return context.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, parameters);
    }
}
```

So now when testing `IUnitOfWork` can be easily mocked with your mocking framework of choice.

```
var mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
```